# Как ввести дату с формы jsp в базу?

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, java, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть форма регистрации на jsp, все данные вводятся нормально, не получается ввести только дату (поле birthdate типа Date), дата вводится с календаря. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно ввести дату в моем примере. После ввода данных на форме появляется такая ошибка:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property birthdate; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Date for value 1995-08-10; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Вот форма:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="calendar" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<t:template>
    <form:form method="post" action="/add" commandName="user">
        <div class="form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="name">
                        <spring:message code="label.name"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="name"/></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="surname">
                        <spring:message code="label.surname"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="surname"/></td>
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="surname"/></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="gender"><spring:message code="label.gender"/></form:label></td>
                    <td>
                        <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="male" /><spring:message code="label.male"/>
                        <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="female" /><spring:message code="label.female"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="birthdate">
                    <spring:message code="label.birthdate"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="birthdate"/></td>                                      
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="birthdate" /></span>            </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="address">
                        <spring:message code="label.address"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="address"/></td>
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="address"/></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="tel">
                        <spring:message code="label.tel"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="tel"/></td>
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="tel"/></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="email">
                        <spring:message code="label.email"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="email"/></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="login">
                        <spring:message code="label.login"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="login"/></td>
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="login"/></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="password">
                        <spring:message code="label.password"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:password path="password"/></td>
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="password"/></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="confirmPassword">
                        <spring:message code="label.confirmpassword"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:password path="confirmPassword"/></td>
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="confirmPassword"/></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="category"><spring:message code="label.category"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td>
                        <form:select path="category.id">
                            <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
                            <form:options items="${categoryList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
                        </form:select>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="comment">
                        <spring:message code="label.comment"/>:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:textarea path="comment" rows="5" cols="25" name="text"/></td>
                    <td><span class="error2"><form:errors path="comment"/></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><span class="signup-button"><input type="submit"
                             value="<spring:message code="label.add"/>"/></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</t:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем я понял, при чем тут jsp, но если погуглить по описанию вашей проблемы, то можно найти вот такое решение, возможно, поможет.

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
                dateFormat, true));
    }
```

Добавить в контроллер, только в вашем случае формат будет "yyyy-MM-dd".